# expressjs - using Node How to send error back to Backbone?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express

I am not able to send the error back to backbone, when i am not get the username nor password.. on success I am getting success message properly.  any one correct my node code pelease?

here is my node code:

```
    var 
    http    = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    path    = require('path'),
    jade    = require('jade'),
    stylus  = require('stylus'),
    nib     = require('nib'),
    fs      = require('fs'),
    app     = express();

    function compile(str, path) {
      return stylus(str)
        .set('filename', path)
        .set('compress', true)
        .use(nib());
    }

    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.set('views', __dirname);
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(app.router);

    app.use(stylus.middleware({
        src: __dirname + '/ui',
        compile:compile,
        compress: true
    }));

    app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/ui'));

    app.all('/', function(req, res, next){

        var html;

        fs.readFile('ui/index.html', function(err, data){
            if(err) throw err;
            var fn = jade.compile(data);
            html = fn({name:'Oleg'});

            res.send(html);
        });

    });

    app.post('/home', function(req, res, error){
        var name = req.body.userName,
            password = req.body.password;

if(!name){
return "failed" //not working
}

if(!password){
return "failed" //not working
}

        var successObj = {
            "userName" : name,
            "password" : password
        }

           return res.send(successObj); //i am getting proper out put in backbone. how to send error in case name or password not there?
    });


    http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function(){
        console.log("i am listning to 3000!");
    });
```

Comment: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send

Comment: I am not able to get any idea from this url.

Comment: Instead of `return "failed"` try `return res.send(500, { error: 'failed' });`

Comment: tried, not working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTTP status codes in your REST service to specify error. Here is the list of status codes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

In your case 401 could be used.

res.send method can accept status code as the first parameter:
http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send

you can also use res.json and specify the details of the error
http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.json

for example: res.json(401, { error: 'Wrong password' })

Comment: I written as like your example, but still not working